# Prevent submission of Created Entry after a submitChanges

Tags: sapui5

I have a odata model v2. When I create a new entry by using [createEntry](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createEntry) function it does not submit the newly created entry to the backend. When I use [submitChanges](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/submitChanges) function with a `groupId` I expected the only thing that is submitted be the list of requests with that group id.

```
oDataModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: sGroupId,
    success: function(oData){
        console.log("Done", oData);
    },
    error:  function(oError ){
        console.log("Failed", oError);
    }
});
```

Uptil now everything going well, until I will try to create the next entry by using `createEntry`. Please note it is after a successful `submitChange`. Then this newly created entry is submitted to the backend automatically. Now the question is how I can prevent odata model from auto submission of created entries. "I use `sGroupId` and I expect only this submission done only one time."